# Error Locating Reference of NuGet Package

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am working on a project with a small team. We use Git for Visual Studio for version control.
The problem is that when I sync the project, visual studio can not locate dlls that are added using NuGet package manager by other team members. How can I resolve the problem?
The Error is:

```
Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because Git will only record change inside its folder, maybe you only push the `packages.config` to git remote server, so when the other team member pull it, your team member only got the setting like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

without get the actual `Newtonsoft.Json` while pull it.

so your team(other than you) need to uninstall and reinstall that nuget packages. Or i dont know if maybe you can locate and copy also your dll to your friend without uninstall the nuget setting.

Comment: maybe you can also try to **allow nuget to manage packages** so nuget will automatically downloading missing packages

Answer (score 0):

sometimes git restore helps (contextmenu on the solution)

some time that fails though and you have to manually use the nugetconsole to do something like update-package -reinstall 
(http://blog.nuget.org/20121231/a-quick-tutorial-on-update-package-command.html)